# Expand vector n times to fit larger matrix without using np.tile() or creating a new vector

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matrix, vector

I have matrix `(shape=3,12)` and want to do column-to-column multiplication with vector `kkk` `(len=6)`. I can do it by making `np.tile(kkk,2)` to expand it as 12 element vector. But I wonder there is a way to just multiply it straightforwardly without using `np.tile` (or anything that I have to make a new vector just for multiplication)?

```
>>> matrix=np.ones([3,12])

>>> kkk
array([ 0.008,  0.595,  0.278,  0.103,  0.014,  0.002])

>>> matrix*np.tile(kkk,2)
array([[ 0.008,  0.595,  0.278,  0.103,  0.014,  0.002,  0.008,  0.595, 0.278,  0.103,  0.014,  0.002],
       [ 0.008,  0.595,  0.278,  0.103,  0.014,  0.002,  0.008,  0.595, 0.278,  0.103,  0.014,  0.002],
       [ 0.008,  0.595,  0.278,  0.103,  0.014,  0.002,  0.008,  0.595, 0.278,  0.103,  0.014,  0.002]])
```

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Reshape to split `matrix`'s second axis into two with the last one of length `6`, which we could then lead into element-wise multiplication with `kkk` and finally reshape back to its original shape -

```
(matrix.reshape(3,2,6)*kkk).reshape(3,12)
```

Sample run -

```
In [47]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(3,12))

In [48]: matrix = np.random.randint(0,9,(3,12))

In [49]: kkk = np.random.randint(0,9,(6))

# As proposed in this post
In [50]: (matrix.reshape(3,2,6)*kkk).reshape(3,12)
Out[50]: 
array([[21, 32,  1,  5,  8,  6, 12, 12,  2,  0, 16,  9],
       [18, 12,  7,  8, 40, 24,  3, 12,  1,  2, 48, 15],
       [15, 20,  1,  0, 16, 12,  3, 32,  7,  8, 48, 24]])

# As proposed in the question with tiling (for verification)
In [52]: matrix*np.tile(kkk,2)
Out[52]: 
array([[21, 32,  1,  5,  8,  6, 12, 12,  2,  0, 16,  9],
       [18, 12,  7,  8, 40, 24,  3, 12,  1,  2, 48, 15],
       [15, 20,  1,  0, 16, 12,  3, 32,  7,  8, 48, 24]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
list(kkk) * 2 * matrix
array([[ 0.008,  0.595,  0.278,  0.103,  0.014,  0.002,  0.008,  0.595, 0.278,  0.103,  0.014,  0.002],
    [ 0.008,  0.595,  0.278,  0.103,  0.014,  0.002,  0.008,  0.595, 0.278,  0.103,  0.014,  0.002],
    [ 0.008,  0.595,  0.278,  0.103,  0.014,  0.002,  0.008,  0.595, 0.278,  0.103,  0.014,  0.002]])
```

For my machine, I also get the following result, which is mildly faster for the best:

```
%timeit list(kkk) * 2 * matrix
The slowest run took 12.40 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.29 µs per loop

%timeit matrix * np.tile(kkk, 2)
The slowest run took 5.91 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 10 µs per loop
```